# How to convert existing redmine wiki from textile to markdown?

Tags: ruby, markdown, redmine, textile

I want to use markdown as my redmine wiki engine.

I installed the markdown plugin and it worked well.

The only question is, how can I convert those old wiki (textile) into markdown so they can be displayed correctly?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since this is a once-only task why not [`pandoc -f textile -t markdown` oldfile.text -o newfile.md](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/demos.html)? Try it at [Try Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/try).

Comment: That came to my mind at the first place, but I failed to do cabal install cabal-install on my centOs 5. I'll give it a try next time.

Comment: Just a quick note: If anyone happens to be using the [Redmine CKEditor](http://www.redmine.org/plugins/redmine-ckeditor) plugin, all versions since [1.0.18](https://github.com/a-ono/redmine_ckeditor/commit/383da5d60b2832757493cf65dc418c8ce2cff91c#diff-cb3e0f2c76a671c083e8f001970f4631) include a rake task that allows a source and target format to be specified.

Answer (score 11):

I wrote a rake task to convert all wiki pages and their versions to markdown.

Put this into `lib/tasks/convert_textile_to_markdown.rake`:

```
task :convert_textile_to_markdown => :environment do
  require 'tempfile'
  WikiContent.all.each do |wiki|
    ([wiki] + wiki.versions).each do |version|
      textile = version.text
      src = Tempfile.new('textile')
      src.write(textile)
      src.close
      dst = Tempfile.new('markdown')
      dst.close

      command = [
        "pandoc",
        "--no-wrap",
        "--smart",
        "--strict",
        "-f",
        "textile",
        "-t",
        "markdown",
        src.path,
        "-o",
        dst.path,
      ]
      system(*command) or raise "pandoc failed"

      dst.open
      markdown = dst.read

      # remove the \ pandoc puts before * and > at begining of lines
      markdown.gsub!(/^((\\[*>])+)/) { $1.gsub("\\", "") }

      # add a blank line before lists
      markdown.gsub!(/^([^*].*)\n\*/, "\\1\n\n*")

      version.update_attribute(:text, markdown)
    end
  end
end
```

And run:

```
bundle exec rake convert_textile_to_markdown RAILS_ENV=production
```

Comment: This works great in redmine 2.5.2 (after my edit of filename and the RAILS_ENV)

Comment: Worked flawlessly for our Redmine 2.6. I had to `apt-get install pandoc` first.

Comment: This worked nice (redmine 2.6.1.stable on windows), but with a few quirks:
* I had to install pandoc, eg. with chocolatey: `choco install pandoc`
* for some files pandoc failed - i changed raise "pandoc failed" to puts "pandoc failed" to ignore these errors * bulleted lists (using *) contained slashes (\\) at the end of lines

Answer (score 2):

Building upon [Michaël's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19876009/37706), here is a tool to migrate from Textile to Markdown. It will migrate all content (comment, wiki, issue, message, news, document, project and journal). And it will also fixes several incompatibility between Redmine's Textile and pandoc's.

It's over there: https://github.com/Ecodev/redmine_convert_textile_to_markown

Answer (score 1):

When I tried to convert the markdown file into textile file by above pandoc command(pandoc version is 1.12.4.2),Redmine could not display CodeBlock properly. So it is better that had been written CodeBlock in a pre element.

original is bellow.

```
~~~
% foo bar
~~~
```

converted one is bellow.

```
bc. % foo bar
% foo bar
```

-> This could not be displayed in redmine as a CodeBlock.

You should write CodeBlock as a pre element beforehand.

```
<pre>
 % foo bar
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just used [redmine_reformat](https://www.redmine.org/plugins/redmine_reformat) on a redmine 4.1.1 system with ruby 2.6.6 and it seemed to work fine.  It does not currently work for redmine 5.0.  In our case we were migrating to redmine 5.x so we did the switch in the 4.1.1 system, deleted the plugin and then  migrated to 5.x.